# JavaScript ベンチマーク関数などで実行する関数と引数を渡して動作させたい

Tags: javascript

こんにちは。
一般的なJavaScriptのWebサイトでは、この手のテクニックがみつからず、検索しようにも検索ワードも特定できないので、ご質問します。

ベンチマーク関数などで、以下のように動かしたいのですが、記述方法がわかりません。
疑似コードです

```
var benchMark = function (loopCount, f, args1, args2, args3 …) {
  for … loopCount {
    f(args1, args2, args3…)
  }
}
```

ベンチマーク関数の呼び出し時に、関数fとその引数をわたして、
ベンチマーク関数の内部で、関数fに引数を渡して実行させたいのです。
fに対しては、任意個数の引数をわたしたいです。

もちろん、引数なしのものでしたら簡単でした。
サンプルコードをのせておきます。HTMLです。

やり方をご存知な方おられましたら、教えてください。
あるいは、無理、という情報や、参考になるページを教えていただくだけでも

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
<script>

  var benchMark = function (loopCount, f, args) {
    var
      i, max, 
      startTime, endTime;
    startTime = new Date();
    for (var i = 1, max = loopCount - 1; i <= max; i+=1) {
      f();
    }
    endTime = new Date();
    return endTime - startTime;
  };

  var test1 = function () {
    return '';
  };
  console.log(benchMark(1000000, test1));
  console.log('test finish');

</script>
  </head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`args` が配列（の形で実行する関数の引数を渡す）なら[apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) を使って`f.apply(null, args);` のように実行できます。

```js
function expression2(x, a, b, c){
  console.log(x*(a*x + b) + c);//動作確認のため
  return a*x*x + b*x + c;
}

function benchMark(loopCount, f, args) {
  //while(loopCount--) {
    f.apply(null, args);
  //}
}

benchMark(1000000, expression2, [1,2,3,4]);
```

普通に引数の並びとして書く場合、[arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments)変数と[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)を使って配列に変換します。

```js
function expression2(x, a, b, c){
  console.log(x*(a*x + b) + c);//動作確認のため
  return a*x*x + b*x + c;
}
function expression1(x, a, b){
  console.log(a*x + b);//動作確認のため
  return a*x + b;
}

function benchMark(loopCount, f) {
  //loopCount と f は含めないようにsliceして配列を作る。
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 2)
  //関数の呼び出し以外は省略
  f.apply(null, args);
}

benchMark(1000000, expression2, 2,1,2,3);
benchMark(1000000, expression1, 5,4,6);
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。お返事すこしおくれました。
大変よいテクニック、ありがとうございます。活用させてもらっております。

Answer (score 1):

オーバーヘッドとかは無視してますが、ES2015ならこのように書けます。

```js
function bench (times, func, ...args) {
  const startTime = new Date();
  for(let i=0;i<times;i++) {
    func(...args);
  }
  const endTime = new Date();
  return endTime - startTime;

}

const test1 = function (arg) {
  return arg;
};

console.log(bench(1000000, test1, 'arg1'));
console.log('test finish');
```

もしES2015に非対応の古いブラウザ等も考慮する必要がある場合は[babel](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code=function%20bench%20(times%2C%20func%2C%20...args)%20%7B%0A%20%20const%20startTime%20%3D%20new%20Date()%3B%0A%20%20for(let%20i%3D0%3Bi%3Ctimes%3Bi%2B%2B)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20func(...args)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20const%20endTime%20%3D%20new%20Date()%3B%0A%20%20return%20endTime%20-%20startTime%3B%0A%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20test1%20%3D%20function%20(arg)%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20arg%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aconsole.log(bench(1000000%2C%20test1%2C%20'arg1'))%3B%0Aconsole.log('test%20finish')%3B%0A)とかを参考にしてみてください

Comment: ありがとうございます。(を避けてとか書いてあるけど、これはお礼を述べざるをえないです。)
すっげー！！！

自分は、まだ、ES2015環境は使ってないのですが、
babelのリンク先みて、とても学べます。
bableのページの使い方も同時に学ぶ事ができました。ありがとうございます。

元ネタというか、こんな使い方をしたかった動機ネタは、こちらになります。

[JavaScript で全置換(正規表現も使った)の速度比較 - Qiita](http://qiita.com/standard-software/items/d86a91dac6f7f317087c)